# How to handle a SIGSEGV with jffi / jnr?

Tags: java, segmentation-fault, ffi, jnr

The Java VM crash with a SIGSEGV in a docker container. On all other systems it is working as expected.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000007966, pid=188, tid=189
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.2+8 (17.0.2+8) (build 17.0.2+8)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.2+8 (17.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000007966
```

and the stack trace

```
Current thread (0x00007fbdfa103040):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=189, stack(0x00007fbdff179000,0x00007fbdff279ac8)]

Stack: [0x00007fbdff179000,0x00007fbdff279ac8],  sp=0x00007fbdff277c38,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x0000000000007966

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.kenai.jffi.Foreign.invokeN3O1(JJJJJLjava/lang/Object;III)J+0
j  com.kenai.jffi.Invoker.invokeN3(Lcom/kenai/jffi/CallContext;JJJJILjava/lang/Object;Lcom/kenai/jffi/ObjectParameterStrategy;Lcom/kenai/jffi/ObjectParameterInfo;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/kenai/jffi/ObjectParameterStrategy;Lcom/kenai/jffi/ObjectParameterInfo;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/kenai/jffi/ObjectParameterStrategy;Lcom/kenai/jffi/ObjectParameterInfo;)J+126
j  de.digitalcollections.openjpeg.lib.libopenjp2$jnr$ffi$1.opj_read_header(Ljnr/ffi/Pointer;Ljnr/ffi/Pointer;Ljnr/ffi/byref/PointerByReference;)Z+190
```

What can I do to solve this problem with jffi / jnr? How can I receive more details about the problem?

Comment: Of course in native code. It is jnr (Java Native Runtime). I know that it is a bug. But in which component is the bug? How can I find more details over the cause of it.

Comment: What this help? I know that it crash inside the native/proxy method opj_read_header. But what is the cause? And why only on some systems? What is wrong with this systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the crash on Linux was a inkompatible native libraries for the target OS. The native library was compiled with `glibc` and the OS with the crash use `musl`. It was not a bug in any of the libraries.

To solve the problem we bundle now a second version of the library. And differ with the follow code:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder( "ldd", "/bin/ls" );
Process process = builder.start();
InputStream input = process.getInputStream();
process.waitFor( 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
String content = new String( input.readAllBytes() );
LogManager.getConfigLogger().debug( content );
boolean isMuslLibrary = content.contains( "musl-" );
```

More details are in the issue comments: https://github.com/dbmdz/imageio-jnr/issues/192

Open is the question why `loadLibrary` not throw an error or how an Java developer can find it.